# Facebook Connect: How to auto login user only when he's coming via Facebook App

Tags: facebook, autologin

I've recently implemented the Facebook Connect on my website. 
Everythin works fine so far. When a User visits my site (not via Facebook App) and clicks on the FB Connect Button, he'll be logged in. 
There's no auto login implemented, so a returning user can decide by himself everytime whether he wants to connect with my site or not and has full control.

But in the case someone uses my Facebook App on Facebook, I'd like him to autologin, since it doesn't make sense to login into my site first.

Does someone has a good idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually having the same problem as a newbie. I've just resorted to redirecting the page to the facebook app login page using html inside of my php script.

```
// if not logged in
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
echo '<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Refresh" 
      content="0;url='.$loginUrl.'"/>
  </head>';
```

I get the proper facebook app login page using the fb API, and then I just redirect the user to that page. Once they're logged in they get transferred back to my app automatically by fb. There's probably some built in fb API functionality that does this better, but I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could just check for the signed_request parameter, which (if you have it configured in the app settings) will be sent automatically when your page is loaded inside the Facebook framework. Decoding that will get you the userid which you can then use to log him in to your site as well.